# Cant get validation erros to work in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot get validation errors to work. I have a create product page which has two form_for's One for products and one for photos. When a product doesnt upload you get sent to redirect_to new_product_path

**product controller**

```
def new 
  @product = Product.new
  @photo = Photo.new
end

def create
  check_for_image = Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user)
  if check_for_images == []
    redirect_to products_new_path, :notice => "Add an image then press start before submit"
  else 
    @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).update_all(:product_id => @product.id)
      render "show", notice: "Product created!"
    else
      redirect_to new_product_path #, :flash => { :error => "Test!" }
      # render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

I tried to do render "new" instead of redirect_to but i get undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class with the error pointing to the photo form for

**haml create product page**

```
= form_for @photo, :html => { :multipart => true, :id => "fd" } do |f|
  %span Add files...
  = f.file_field :image

= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { id: "fd", multipart: true } do |f| 
  - if @product.errors.any?
    .error_messages
      %h2 Form is invalid
      %ul
        - for message in @product.errors.full_messages
          %li
            = message
  %p
    = f.text_field :name, placeholder: "Name"
  %p
    = f.text_field :price, class: "auto", data: { a_sign: "$ " }, placeholder: "Price" 
  %p
    = f.text_field :description, placeholder: "Description"

  %p.button.start
    = f.submit
```

**product model**

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :name, presence: true, length:  { minimum: 5 }
validates :price, presence: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 3.00 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first you need to know difference between `redirect_to` & `render`

```
redirect_to :action => 'new' #It will call the method 'new' and then it will call 
                              #respective file. In this case it is `new.haml`


render :action => 'new' #It will call `new.haml` directly without calling method 'new'
```

So when you used `render :action => 'new'` it will not get `@photo` and hence it is giving error `undefined method`model_name' for NilClass:Class`either you have to handle`nil` on view or

It will fixed when you
Change

```
redirect_to new_product_path
```

To

```
@photo = Photo.new
render :action => 'new'
```

Comment: it should be just `render :action => 'new'` without `@photo = Photo.new`, a new photo will be initialized in new action.

Comment: @rmagnum2002:- Nope, when we used `render :action => 'new'` it will not call the method `new` and hence will not able to access `@photo`

Comment: rails generates a default controller with  `format.html { render action: "new" }` without any `Class.new` initialization, it renders an action not a partial, and new action means it will render `def new` and it has the `Photo.new` in there. Right?

Comment: http://pastie.org/8148612  it's a controller generated by scaffold, and there is only `render action: 'new'`, nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

`render` will **render** a particular view **using the instance variables available in the action**. For example if a render was used for the new action, when a user goes to /new, the new action in the controller is called, instance variables are created and then passed to the new view. Rails creates the html for that view and returns it back to the user’s browser. This is what you would consider a normal page load.

`redirect_to` will send a **redirect** to the user’s browser telling it to **re-request a new URL**. Then the browser will send a new request to that URL and it will go through the action for that URL, oblivious to the fact that it was redirected to. None of the variables created in the action that caused the redirect will be available to the redirected view. This is what happens when you click on ‘Create’ in a form and the object is created and you’re redirected to the edit view for that object.

so you had no validation errors because each time you did a redirect a new instance was created with no errors.

**2 lines** you have to change:

`render "show", notice: "Product created!"`
 and 
`redirect_to new_product_path`

not sure about this:
`redirect_to products_new_path, :notice => "Add an image then press start before subm`it" it's not clear what it does and how your app should behave.

**your controller:**

```
def new 
  @product = Product.new
  @photo = Photo.new
end

def create
  check_for_image = Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user)
  if check_for_images == []
    redirect_to products_new_path, :notice => "Add an image then press start before submit"
  else 
    @product = current_user.products.create(params[:product])
    if @product.save
      Photo.where(:product_id => nil, :user_id => current_user).update_all(:product_id => @product.id)
      redirect_to @product, notice: "Product created!"
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end
end
```

**more:**

[Are redirect_to and render exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable)

http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313