# when to render with instance variable, and when to redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

My `new` and `edit` pages depend on an `@important_data` instance variable that is not used in the `create` and `update` actions.

As a result my page can't render the `new` page upon failure.

```
def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])
  if @my_object.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render action: "new"
    #this can't render because the page asks for an @important_data variable that's not defined.
  end
end
```

Which of the two solutions below should I choose?
What are the advantages/disadvantages of each?

**OPTION 1: declare @important_data prior to render**

```
def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])
  if @my_object.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    @important_data = ImportantData.all
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

**OPTION 2: Redirect**

```
def create
  @my_object = MyObject.new(params[:my_object])
  if @my_object.save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    redirect_to new_my_object_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `render`, you're using `@my_object` with the attributes updated from `params[:my_object]`.  Most of the case, this is what you want.  When you show the page to the user, you want to preserve the changes they made to the form and show them the errors.

When you use `redirect`, you're doing a different and additional request so the parameters submitted from the form are not preserved (unless you pass them in your call to redirect and build them up in the controller action).

So in most cases, you'll definitely want to declare `@important_data` when the validation fails.  I can't think of a case where you'd want to redirect.

Comment: Thanks @jvnill. I found your answer to be most informative, as you mentioned that the `@my_object` doesn't reset in the case of a render, which makes sense. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Offcourse, the Option1 will work best, since you are rendering new in case of errors only. Also, redirection li'l bit mess up the user experience, it will take a bit long to render the page again with same query @important_data  = .... running again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use **OPTION1**

> So the place where redirect_to should be used is when you're doing a HTTP POST request and you don't want the user to resubmit the request when it's done (which may cause duplicate items and other problems).
>
> In Rails, when a model fails to be saved, render is used to redisplay the form with the same entries that was filled previously. This is simpler because if you use redirect, you'll have to pass the form entries either using parameters or session. The side effect is that if you refresh the browser, it will try to resubmit the previous form entries. This is acceptable because because it will probably fail the same way, or if it's successful now, it was what the user should expect in the first place anyway.

The above answer is referenced from: [Are redirect_to and render exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable)