# Flash isn't updated upon redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here are the actions for my messages controller:

```
 def new
     @message = Message.new 
 end 

 def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.valid?

      Contactform.contact(@message.name, @message.town, @message.email, @message.content).deliver              
      redirect_to 'messages#new', flash: { success: "Sent Message" }

    else

      redirect_to 'messages#new', flash: { alert: "Message Error" } 

    end
  end
```

This is what I want to happen:

I go to the 'new' route, a @message instance is created, and in the 'new' view there is a form where we can update this 'Message' instance' attributes.

Now, I'm following a tutorial, but it seems a little work-aroundy. When we 'submit' the form, we are automatically taken to the 'create' action, and a second message instance is created and populated with the old instances attributes.

If the attributes pass the Message model's validations, the attributes are passed into the 'Contactform' mailer's 'contact' action, which delivers the message. We are then redirected to the 'new' view, and the flash is populated with a "Sent Message" string, that we can see when we arrive at the 'new' view.

If the attributes fail the Message model's validations, we are then redirected to the 'new' view, and the flash is populated with a "Message Error" string, that we can see when we arrive at the 'new' view.

**What actually happens**

Everything works perfectly, apart from the flash. Once it's populated with either the 'success' or 'alert' message, it doesn't change until I browse to another page. Then it gets the updated message, on a new page, so I think because I'm coming back to the same location, the flash isn't updated for some reason.

How can I get the flash to behave normally, despite us coming back to the same page?

**Update**

Just to say again, it works perfectly if I get redirected to another page. Just because it's the same page, the flash doesn't get updated.

Also, I now have this in the view: Still doesn't do anything.

```
<% if !flash.empty? %>  
    <% flash.each do |index, value| %>
        <div class = "alert alert-<%= index %>"> <%= value %></div>
    <% end %>
    <% flash[:error] = flash[:message] = flash[:notice] = nil %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So, it's the flash on the redirect to messages#new that's not being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the flash to show up within the same request (i.e. without a redirect taking place), you'll need to use flash.now.  Here's the explanation in the rails docs:

> By default, adding values to the flash will make them available to the next request, but sometimes you may want to access those values in the same request. For example, if the create action fails to save a resource and you render the new template directly, that's not going to result in a new request, but you may still want to display a message using the flash

See section 5.2.1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

Comment: Saw your other (very similar) question here, just now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014515/flash-doesnt-clear-after-being-viewed

Comment: I'm using the redirect method now though.