# using render or redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form

```
<%= form_tag update_path do %>
         <%= text_field_tag :test_input, @text %>
         <%= submit_tag "update" %>
<% end %>

#mycontroller
def update
    @text= 'abcde'
    render  :max_channel #redirect_to :max_channel
end
```

if I use render, it update my text_field_tag but it change my url to localhost:3000/update.
redirect_to don't update my text and I don't know why. How can I use redirect_to to update text_field_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`redirect_to` will make the browser request a new page(here is your max_channel), and current context will be lost. That's why you cannot update `@text` in the `max_channel` page.

while `render` will use current context to render `max_channel` page.

you can get more from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect-to.

You can save `@text` to somewhere(say your `sqlite`) and retrieve it in the method corresponding to `max_channel`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use redirect_to then you will need to pass the parameters with the request since the redirect_to goes to a different URL.  Some good background information on redirect and render is given in the SO question  [Are redirect_to and render exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable)