# How does rails populate forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I create a scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Cat name:string age:integer
```

and I add a presence validation on the Cat model's age attribute:

```
validates :age, presence: true
```

When I attempt to create a cat via the form, **and put in the cat's name but purposely leave out the cat's age** the controller bounces me back to the form **but that cat's name is still present in the name field!**

How is this happening?

I would have thought the

```
@cat = Cat.new
```

would replace all of the invalid cat's attributes. Maybe if it were `@cat ||= Cat.new` I could understand that more.

Also, how can I make this behaviour happen in a more complex rails app? I have a simple forum where `topics` has_many `replies`. I create my new replies via a form in my `topic show` view:

*topic#show:*

```
@reply = Reply.new
```

*topic/show.html.erb:*

```
<%= form_for [@toplic, @reply] do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :name placeholder: 'Create a new name...' %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description, placeholder: 'Create a new description...', rows: 5 %><br>
    <%= f.submit 'Create Discussion' %>

<% end %>
```

While everything works perfectly, when I purposely leave out a reply's name, though I am redirected back to the form and an error flash shows, my form is completely empty. All of the attributes have vanished? Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to understanding how this works is to realize that in the case of a form failure, the controller action is not rerun, but rather the template is rendered using the existing state from the action.

In a typical Rails scaffold, your `create` action will look like this

```
def create
  @cat = Cat.new(cat_params) # instance variable is initialized with the form values
  if @cat.save
    redirect_to @cat, notice: 'Success!'
  else
    # in the case of form failure, we will re-render the 'new' template
    # this will NOT rerun the entire 'new' action, thus the @cat variable
    # will still maintain the values from the form that we gave it above
    render 'new'

    # note the difference if we had instead done a redirect_to; this would
    # cause the CatsController#new action to be re-run which would reinitialize
    # the @cat variable according to the code within the 'new' action
    # redirect_to new_cat_url
  end
end
```

For your more complex example, you'll want to follow the same procedure, making sure you just re-render the form and don't redirect to another action (which will cause the state to be lost).

```
# TopicsController
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @reply = Reply.new
end

# RepliesController
def create
  @reply = Reply.new(reply_params) # init the var with the form values
  if @reply.save
    redirect_to @topic, notice: 'Success!'
  else
    # this is the key - we need to re-render the template of the previous action
    # in this case, it would be the TopicsController#show template
    render 'topics/show'

    # Remember - if we instead do a redirect_to @topic, then we will lose the form
    # values which are currently set in the @reply variable. 
  end
end
```

In short, make sure you recognize when you are *redirecting to a new action* versus just *re-rendering a template*.

---

One important GOTCHA to be aware of when re-rendering a template is that you must make sure that all the instance variables which exist for the controller action are available when you render the template.

For example,

```
# TopicsController
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @reply = Reply.new
  @foo = Foo.new
end

# RepliesController

before_action :set_topic

def create
  @reply = Reply.new(reply_params)
  if @reply.save
    # ...
  else
    # we need to remember to set up a @foo variable here otherwise it will be undefined
    # when used within the 'show' template
    @foo = Foo.new
    render 'topics/show'
end

protected

def set_topic
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
end
```

Comment: Okay, but why does the `@foo` variable need to be re-created in the create action and not @topic and @reply?

Comment: Great question. It's because the `@reply` and `@topic` variables were already set within the `create` action (`@reply` in the first line of the method, and `@topic` in a `before_filter`). The `@foo` variable, however, is never set within the `create` code, which is why you need to manually set it before re-rendering the `show` template.

Comment: Ah, I see now, great!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so, you go go /cat/new. Rails' route for this URL runs the method `CatsController#new`, which renders the new.html.erb template. You put in your data, then hit submit. The action for this form is to POST to /cats, which runs the `CatsController#create` method. This method does this following:

```
@cat = Cat.new(cat_params)
```

It then tries to save the Cat. If it succeeds, it redirects you to the Cat's URL. If not, it re-renders the new.html.erb template. That's where the name comes from — the `CatsController#update` method creates its Cat from the values you put into the original form.

Answer (score 0):

For a typical scaffold create action:

```
 # POST /products
 # POST /products.json
  def create
    @product = Product.new(params[:product])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @product, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" } #will re-submit
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The magic happens in the `render` method! which will **submit the previous POST request** (won't go back to the `new` action while a redirect will do), this way the submited values are still there. (check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable) for more details)

That's said, this behavior relies on following the convention, however sometimes you need to give it a hand specially with some inputs (e.g selects, checkboxes, radio) might require extra setup using `selected` or `value` options