# "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" only after new user creation. Strange behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

> **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:**
>
> <% @users.each do |user| %>

Admins in my app can create users manually through a user dashboard that I created. However, after clicking the button to create a new user, some strange things happen.

First, I am presented with `"undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass"`, with a reference to the `Users Index View`  (which is where admins are redirected after user creation. If I refresh the page, the browsers URL box still states that it's on the `Users Index` page, however, the screen displays the `New User` page with statement saying that the entered `User Email` is already taken. If I manually go to the `User Index` page, then I can see the User added successfully, and I am **NOT** presented with the `undefined method` error. What the heck! I know I have some messy code, but I have no idea why this is happening.

**Users Controller Excerpt:**

```
def index
    @users = User.all
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { render :index, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

**Users Index View Excerpt:**

```
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= user.admin ? "<i style='color:green' class='glyphicon glyphicon-flash'><strong>Admin</strong></i>".html_safe : " " %></td>
        <td><strong><%= link_to user.email,user %></strong></td>
        <td><span class="badge"><%= user.sign_in_count %></span></td>
        <td><%= user.activated ? "<i style='color:green' class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></i>".html_safe : "<i style='color:red' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>".html_safe %></td>
        <td><b>
            <%= link_to user do %>
              <span class="badge"><%= user.apps.count %></span> View
            <% end %>
        </b></td>
        <td><%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'><strong> Manage</strong></i>".html_safe, edit_user_path(user), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-xs' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i> Destroy".html_safe, user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

**Routes File Excerpt:**

```
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'u'
resources :users

  devise_scope :user do
    get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :login
    get 'logout', to: 'devise/sessions#destroy', as: :logout
    get 'user/edit', to: 'devise/registrations#edit', as: :change_password
  end
```

Let me know if you'd like any additional code. **You can find the entire app on GitHub here:**
https://github.com/nickdb93/QwesteraCONNECT/tree/completion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is perfect:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
```

This works because you changed render to redirect_to.  Render will render a view with the instance variables it has access to in that action.  In your original problem, you called render in the #create action.  This didn't work because the #create action doesn't have access to the @users instance variable.

redirect_to tells the browser to re-request a new url.  In your working solution, you are telling the browser to request the url that goes to the #index action.  The index action will then set the @users instance variable and render :index

These resources explain the difference between render and redirect_to better than I ever could:
[Are redirect_to and render exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable)

[Render and Redirect](https://gist.github.com/jcasimir/1210155)

Comment: @IanAnge Thank you for the pointers! I new they weren't interchangeable, but I never knew what differentiated them.

Answer (score 2):

I probably didn't solve this the best way, but I found a convenient workaround.

I changed the `if @user.save` action in my `UsersController#create` as follows.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    format.html { render :index, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
```

**was changed to:**

```
respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_path, notice: 'user was successfully created.' }
```

**Please add your input if you have a better way. I'd love to learn the Rails way to do this.**

Comment: That is the correct (and "rails") way of doing it.  You redirect to the new action you want to perform.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Well that's a pleasant surprise hahaha. Thank you for your feedback!