# Rails Todo list why do i get a no method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to build  a todo list but I get a no method error whenever I try to render'index' but when i use render'new' in the controller it works Why does this happen can somebody help me.

**View index.html.erb**

```
<style = "text/css">
  div{
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #FFCC00;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  h2{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  h4{
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    text-align: top;
  }
  #form{
    background-color: #eee;
  }
</style>

<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <div>
      <h2><%= list.name %> <%= link_to 'Trash',list,method: :delete %></h2>
  </div>


<% end %>

<div id ="form">
  <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<br>

<%= link_to 'Add a new task', new_list_path %>
```

**Controller listscontroller.rb**

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @lists = List.all
  end


  def show
  end


  def edit
  end


  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)

    if @list.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else 
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @list.update(list_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @list, notice: 'List was successfully       updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @list }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @list.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def destroy
    @list.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'List was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

  def set_list
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: When you render `index` it tries to iterate through `@lists`, but as `@lists` is `nil` so it throws the error

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: As asked above i am getting a no method error undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass, and i want to know how to fix it

Comment: You didn't mention the error above.  In which case @usmanali is correct.

Comment: I know @lists is nil but why is it and how do i fix it, i am sorry i am a newbie to rails

Comment: @HeisenbergLee You probably have to understand the difference between `render` and `redirect_to`. Please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7494300/515991

Comment: and the answer to your question would be to add `@lists = List.all` just above `render 'index'`. It ll work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an important difference between `render` and `redirect_to`. In your `create` method, if the new `List` could not be saved, you're rendering the `index.html.erb` template. That does not run the `index` method in your controller, it just asks Rails to render the template. The template expects `@lists` to be defined, and it is not, because you did not come through the `index` action.

The typical pattern you want here is actually `render 'new'`. This will render the form again so your user can correct whatever errors there were in the `List` attributes and try to resubmit. You haven't shown us your `new` code, but the usual code looks like:

```
# app/controllers/lists_controller.rb

def new
  @list = List.new
end
```

```
# app/views/lists/new.html.erb

<% form_for @list do %>
  The creation form...
<% end %>
```

When the user is coming in fresh, the `new` action in your controller sets up `@list = List.new` for the form to use. This is also where you can set any default values you'd like. When creation fails and you `render 'new'`, your `create` action has also assigned `@list` with the values the user entered, so rendering `new.html.erb` again will work.

If that's not what you want, and you really do want to take the user to the lists index, use `redirect_to lists_path`. That sends the user's browser back to the `index` action where `@lists` will get assigned and `index.html.erb` can render properly.