# How to render in format.js within the own controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing an ajax get from show to new page. But after the post gets saved it needs to render `/posts/new` page. I get an error saying syntax error. My code below:

posts_controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
     respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @post }

   # format.js { :file => "/posts/new" } *not working
   # format.js { :location => "new_post" } *not working

  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

edi: sorry there was a typo. `end` has been added and the comment has been changed. I don't know how to  render `"/posts/new"` yet.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the end block, and `//` is not a ruby commenting mark, Ruby uses `#`. So:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @post }
      # format.js { :file => "/posts/new" } *not working
      # format.js { :location => "new_post" } *not working
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

About the functionality:

This makes a redirect:

```
format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
```

This renders a page with the entire layout:

```
format.html { render :new }
```

This renders only the page content (that's what you probably want for ajax):

```
format.html { render :new, layout: false }
```

So to render the new page after successful save:

```
if @post.save
  format.html { render :new, layout: false }
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me do a lot of research. The answer you provided did not work as js file started throwing an error. here is the answer:  ` format.html { redirect_to action: "new"}` . Here is the post that was very useful in understanding how redirect and render works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493767/are-redirect-to-and-render-exchangeable

Comment: Note to self: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing an `end`, aligning the statements can help to make this easier to identify.

```
def create
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @post.save
       format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :new, status: :created, location: @post }

       # format.js { :file => "/posts/new" } *not working
       # format.js { :location => "new_post" } *not working
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
end
```

Edit: Yep as dsokurenko points out // is not valid Ruby comment missed that, updated.